# Is it that $\frac{p}{2-p}(n-1)^{(p-2)/p} \leq Cy^{p-2}$, $ p \in (1,2), y \in [(n-1)^{1/p}, n^{1/p}]$?

Tags: calculus, upper-lower-bounds

I found this relationship in a probability book (Durrett, "Probability: Theory and examples", 4th edition; Theorem 2.5.8), though it is just simple calculus:

$$\sum_{m=n}^\infty m^{-2/p} \leq \frac{p}{2-p}(n-1)^{(p-2)/p} \leq Cy^{p-2},$$

where $y \in [(n-1)^{1/p}, n^{1/p}]$. Here, $p \in (1,2)$.

The first inequality comes from comparing the sum with an integral ($\sum_{m=n}^\infty m^{-2/p} \leq \int_{n-1}^\infty x^{-2/p}$), I understand that part. But if $y \in [(n-1)^{1/p}, n^{1/p}]$ and being $f(x) = x^{p-2}$ decreasing, isn't it the case that $\frac{p}{2-p}(n-1)^{(p-2)/p} \geq Cy^{p-2}$? I am assumig that $C$ does not depend on $n$.

I am sorry for asking such an elementary question, but I have spent a bit of a time stuck in that second inequality and cannot find what is wrong with my reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question: Does there exists $C > 0$ such that
$$\forall\,y \in [(n-1)^{1/p}, n^{1/p}],  \frac{p}{2-p}(n-1)^{(p-2)/p} \leq Cy^{p-2}?$$

To make things easier, let's move $y^{p-2}$ to LHS, so that every quantity in the inequality is in the form of $\pm\underbrace{(\dots)}_{\text{positive}}$.

$$\frac{p}{2-p} \frac{(n-1)^{-(2-p)/p}}{y^{-(2-p)}}
= \frac{p}{2-p} \frac{y^{2-p}}{(n-1)^{(2-p)/p}} \le \frac{p}{2-p} \underbrace{\frac{n^{(2-p)/p}}{(n-1)^{(2-p)/p}}}_{\to 1}$$

Since convergent sequence is bounded, simply take $C$ to be any number larger than or equal to $\sup_n (n/(n-1))^{(2-p)/p}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is more indirect than what I have thought. One question, if you mind: what do you mean by "is in the form of +-(...)". Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for upvote and accept.  I meant a sign (+/-) followed by a *positive* quantity.  I find it *difficult* to concentrate with all these changing plus and minus sign and inequality signs.  Therefore, I prefer expressing a negative quantity as $-M$, where $M>0$ unless there's a convention.

Comment: Perfectly clear, thanks for the clarification.